# make new array from 2 arrays same keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Today i found new stack ( maybe stack with me ). I'm working for a new simple PHP framework to learning, but when a need make a array of data to add to database. This array make from 2 array : one is Default array and one left is new request array. i will demo :

`

```
array $default = (
[cat] = '0',
[dog] = '0',
[bird] = '0'
)

array $request = (
[cat] = '10',
[dog] = '12',

[someanimal] = '100'
)
```

`

now i want make a new array with result like this: `array $new = ([cat]='10', [dog]='12', [bird]='0')`.
In PHP may be have some command for this ? or we need make a custom function for?

Thanks everyone for help :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$result = $default;
foreach ($request as $key=>$value) {
  if (isset($result[$key])) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }  
}
```

Or

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_merge($default, $request), $default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this:

```
$finalArray = array_merge($default, $request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php